# Make element curved with css

Tags: html, css

I need to make elements wrapper curved.
I don't provide code, because I don't understand how can I create such effect with css, should I use pseudoelements or how can I do this in another way?
So it should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution for concave top and it involves using the CSS pseudo elements. For example, imagine that our website body looks like this.
e

```
    <body>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="https://www.stockvault.net/data/2007/03/01/102413/thumb16.jpg" />
        </div>
    </body>
```

Then, we add some CSS:

```
    .image-container {
        width: 600px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

    .image-container > img {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    .image-container:before {
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: -50px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: white;
    }
```

You can play with the height and top property of the pseudo element to get different curve style.

You can find fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6thwnvz3/1/

Comment: This answer would be significantly improved by putting the code into a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Using a snippet also makes it more likely for it to be up-voted, because people can quickly verify that your code functions correctly. While snippets shouldn't always be used, for JavaScript/HTML/CSS based questions and answers, they can significantly improve communicating both the problem and solution. When possible to use, a snippet is better than runable code examples that are off-site (e.g. JSFiddle).

Answer (score 3):

It can be simply done for just to curve the top or bottom of any div:

```
div{
    border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
}
```

For concave you can use the pseudo elements.
HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 .div3 {
  position: relative;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  height: 200px;
}
.div1 .div3::after {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px; /* increase height to increase the curvature */
  content: '';
  right: -40%;
  left: -40%;
  bottom: 100%;
  top: auto;
}
```

Comment: but it is only a curved bottom, I need to make a concave top. Is there any css property for this?

Comment: This answer would be significantly improved by putting the code into a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Using a snippet also makes it more likely for it to be up-voted, because people can quickly verify that your code functions correctly. While snippets shouldn't always be used, for JavaScript/HTML/CSS based questions and answers, they can significantly improve communicating both the problem and solution. When possible to use, a snippet is better than runable code examples that are off-site (e.g. JSFiddle).

Answer (score 2):

This could probably be achieved with SVG and clip path (unless you plan to support IE or Edge).

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.img-clipped {
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.001996007984032,0.005882352941176)">
      <path d="M500.995 0H501V121H500.995H0V0H500.995ZM500.995 0C500.148 27.0905 388.322 49 250.5 49C112.678 49 0.852446 27.0906 0.00484801 4.3798e-05L500.995 0Z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
      <path d="M500.995 121L0.00484801 121C0.852446 148.091 112.678 170 250.5 170C388.322 170 500.148 148.091 500.995 121Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>


<img class="img-clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/200" alt="">
```

Note: The original dimensions of this particular SVG were `width="501" height="170"`. So in order to make this work nicely with `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`, I had to scale down the SVG's `<clipPath>` element by 1/501 & 1/170.